# addMenuProvider in fragment in android

Tags: android

why do we pass viewLifecycleOwner and Lifecycle.State.RESUMED to addMenuProvider?
`private fun addOptionMenu() {
val activity = requireActivity()

```
    activity.addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider{
        override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.edit_menu,menu)
        }

        override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
            return when(menuItem.itemId){
                R.id.action_next -> true
                R.id.action_settings -> true
                else -> false
            }
        }

    })
}`
```

what does they do?

I tried to remove them and didn't notice any change

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 `addMenuProvider` i.e.

1. `addMenuProvider(MenuProvider)`
   The menu is added irrespective of the lifecycle & its current state.
2. `addMenuProvider(MenuProvider provider, LifecycleOwner)`
   The menu is added instantly but is removed when the lifecycle hits `ON_DESTROY`.
3. `addMenuProvider(MenuProvider, LifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State)`
   The menu is added when the state is **atleast** the provided state, & is removed when the lifecycle hits `ON_DESTROY`.

Why you ask?
You don't want your app to crash when you click a `MenuItem` & access the view where the `Fragment`'s `View` might have been destroyed.
Example: `TabLayout + ViewPager(2)` & a lot of fragments with default `offscreenPageLimit`.

Hence the lifecycle simply ensures crash safety when you access the `MenuItem`.

Comment: Hi @Darshan, I don't fully understand the different Lifecycle states (RESUMED, CREATED, etc.) in that context. Most of the examples (incl. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.4.0-alpha01) say that RESUMED should be used. I was experimenting with several states but couldn't find a difference in my app (consists of multiple fragments in a tab layout). Can you help?

Comment: `RESUMED` can be called multiple times like when the fragment is made visible in a `ViewPager` after a swipe. `CREATED` means that the menu is added when the Fragment is first instantiated & added to it's host. Say all your Fragments in the TabLayout has menus to be added, then it would make sense to add those menus when that particular fragment is in Resumed state (current selected / visible state). Afaik, if you use `CREATED`, there would be inconsistencies between your resumed Fragments & their respective Menus.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Yes, using RESUMED makes more sense to me for my use case.